# Database Updating issues vb.net (2015)

Tags: vb.net

I am having trouble updating a database in a particular way that's kinda difficult to explain but I'll try. Everything works good as it is the way I have set it up. But now I need to update the value in each cell for one column a row at a time in a For loop. The loop adds the values of six previous cells and I want that sum in a Sum column for each row(record). Currently the sum column contains the wrong sum for each row and the idea is to recalculate and overwrite the old sum column value. Now I'm just a newbie to vb.net and my code will probably look very amateurish to most here so bear with me.
I am using a binding source with the appropriate datasets and table adapters and the code I post is where I'm at at this point. What this code is doing is it gets the right value to overwrite the sum cell but it doesn't write it to the database after each row iteration of the For Loop. Instead it runs through all 3482 records and writes the last rows calculations to every rows sum column cell. Example the sum for the last row is 40 and every cell in the sum column will have 40 for it's value. Now I have tried moving the update section to different location in and out of the first for loop and it pretty much does the same thing or worse. Here's my code below with a follow up after.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim z As Int16, x As Int16, y As Int16, PosX As Int16, PosY As Int16, Result As Int16, SumResult As Int16

    All649_BS.MoveFirst()
    Deltas_BS.MoveFirst()

    For z = 1 To All649_BS.Count

        SumResult = All649_BS.Current(2)

        For x = 3 To 7
            y = x - 1
            PosX = All649_BS.Current(x)
            PosY = All649_BS.Current(y)
            Result = PosX - PosY
            SumResult = SumResult + Result

                            'Deltas_BS.Current(x) = Result
            DeltaSum.Text = SumResult

        Next
        All649_DataSet.AcceptChanges()
        Deltas_BS.Current(9) = SumResult
        Try

            Validate()
            Deltas_BS.EndEdit()
            DeltasTableAdapter.Update(All649_DataSet)

            Messages.Text = ("Update successful")

        Catch ex As Exception

            Messages.Text = ("Update failed")

        End Try

        All649_BS.MoveNext()
        Deltas_BS.MoveNext()
        SumResult = 0

    Next

End Sub
```

This is code I tried at first and when wouldn't work decided to write code to basically rewrite all cells for each row(record) all 3482 of them. But when I set it up like that I deleted all records in the table to write to and stated fresh.  But then the code wouldn't even add new records to the table. I wasted a crap load of time trying to figure out why it wouldn't add a new record just to get started. So I went back to this code. All my other functions that add new records works fine for another table in the dataset and another whole database for another set of tables. Never had an issue til now. One thing I did change that may have caused this problem is I originally had a separate bindsource, dataset, tableadapter for each table in two different databases but it was cluttered and I kinda got a better idea how these things worked and tried to streamline it all. Instead of using a bunch of datasets I made one with ALL the tables I need and then a new bindingsource and tableadapter would be created when I bound a textbox to that one dataset. It was all going fine til I tackled a second table and all went to crap when it wouldn't add new records after I ditched the whole table to rewrite it all with the new sums added. I had to do the same thing to the first table and if I remember right at the moment it succeeded with a few minor difficulties after the code ran which I corrected using Access.

I hope I explained this well enough. I saw another solution for a similar problem and they used something like .rows(i)(6) type of accessing rows and cells via indexes but I don't think you can do that with binding sources and datasets and adapters. In that solution the guy was using a dgv that was bound.

A couple things I forgot ... my update command seems to work but for all cells one same value. UPDATE Deltas SET [Sum] = ? God it was so much easier using VB6. Another weird thing wash happening when I ran the old code trying to rewrite the whole table after deleting all record.. Ran code opened table in Access and it was all out of order. I would resort by date in Access and delete the auto number column and make a new one and save and it would all go back to disordered auto number column all out of whack again. And it would be different every time. I finally got a result where all I had to do was fix the first 10 records then I tried doing the second table using the same approach only difference was instead of a 6 cell sum it was a 7 and the indexes were adjusted accordingly for the extra column. If I think of anything else I'll be back here editing.

Yup I'm back ... one more thing is I use a break point on thhe next line on the 3 to 7 loop and continue thru til it exits then check the sumresult which is always good then step thru to end of validate/update stop there and look at the tableadapter contents for current row and that value is written in and correct for the column but the database update writes the last sumresult (40) to all the cells in the sum column. So I need to find out why the update cannot update that cell in each row as it steps thru the row looper.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out on my own. I took 4 or 5 days off from working on the problem and got back to it last night when I posted my dilemma. Just after my last edit I found the cause. I needed to use a WHERE condition to limit the update to just the record I wanted changed. I wasn't aware that the update does the whole table without that condition.
Thanks anyway for not being able to help me out. LOL What an idiot I am ! Such a simple solution and quite obvious but like I said in the post, I'm still very new to VB.Net